# How to create a repeat group of fields with Gravity Forms

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

I know gravity forms has list field but it's not like what's on this page https://smithpowerproducts.com/parts-request/. How to create something like this? Has a ADD and REMOVE button to add and remove a group of fields?

Answer (score 0):

Not identical but a comparable solution that might be a better fit for this many fields anyways:

https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-nested-forms/